# How to unlink an app from twitter account?

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I used API from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth 
to integrate login feature in my website using oAuth api.

If user want to unlink app from twitter account then how to do that?
I tried to find method in sdk but didn't found.

Answer (score 1):

The user goes to `Settings->Applications` on twitter.com to revoke access. Or, you can use the [`oauth/invalidate_token`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/invalidate_access_token) in your code to reset the token and require the user to login again to get a new one.

Comment: I dont want to do to login in twitter account and remove app access. I want to do using a api similr like unlink app from my twitter account.

Comment: You cannot unlink apps *from your account* via the API, but the application author can invalidate the tokens using the `oauth/invalidate_token` endpoint. As a user, you need to use the Settings.